# Why is my image not showing up for the given latex script?

Tags: graphics

I have used the following script and it's result doesn't shows the result as image in the PDF file and I don't understand why -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\graphicspath{/home/aalpanigrahi/Desktop/LaTeX/fractions/abc.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

For the following figure -
[image]

And it produces the following result -
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `\graphicspath` is used to specify the path to a folder that includes all the images, not to include an image inside the figure environment. You should use `\includegraphics` instead.

Comment: don't use `[!h]`

Answer (score 1):

Use \includegraphics for images.

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{/home/aalpanigrahi/Desktop/LaTeX/fractions/abc}
\end{figure}
```